# Tour of Heroes tutorial -- seems like *ngFor not working

Tags: angular

I've gotten to the point in the tutorial where one creates mock-heroes.ts (an array of hero objects in HEROES); everything up to that point works. I add the `*ngFor` directive in the `<li>` element, but the app doesn't display the list of heroes.

If I take out the `*ngFor` and put in a 'vanilla' `<li>` element (e.g., `<li>New item</li>`), I get the one list element ("New item"). If I add html after the `<ul>...</ul>` element, that shows up.

heroes.component.html:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

mock-heroes.ts:

```
import { Hero } from "./hero";

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

hero.ts:

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

heroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes = HEROES;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I expect to see:

```
   Tour of Heroes!
     My Heroes
   11 Mr. Nice
   12 Narco
   ...
```

I get the first two lines, but not the list of heroes. The console shows me no errors.

Dir structure:

```
src
   app
      files: app.module.ts, app.component.*, hero.ts, mock-heroes.ts
      heroes
         files: heroes.component.*
```

Comment: Can you share your folder structure ?

Comment: Check this out, it's working there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwrq38

Comment: @brunobastosg Thanks for the pointer. My code seems to match that, but doesn't work. I can't see the difference (and I'm sure it's something simple/dumb).

Comment: @AustinTFrench `heroes` is the name of the variable in the component. The naming is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was going on, but I stopped then started the server...and things started working. I'm guessing I had some mistake that I fixed, but the problem was basic enough that the server needed to restart.

Thanks for the various thoughts!

Comment: If you change the angular.json you need "restart" the server. I don't know if it's your case